# Strange border with gradient around submit button. How do I remove?

Tags: html, css, button

I have this weird problem, which I can't seem to get around and I'm not sure why it is here.

I am trying to style my form button and upon styling I have this weird outline that I didn't code in
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqT8W.jpg

Here is the code:

```
button {
  background: #3e779d;
  padding: 12.5px 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle
}
button:hover {
  background: #28597a;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Can anyone shed some light into why this is happening please.

Thank you

HUGE EDIT: Thank you to all. I was missing a semi colon so the code wasn't running for me. All the answers below are correct (its a sign you shouldn't spend so long in front of the screen)

Comment: The button border-style is outset by default. You may want it to be none or solid. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `border:none;` in your button.

```
button {
  background: #3e779d;
  padding: 12.5px 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border:none;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vmtmnupe/)**

Answer (score 1):

That's the default button border. You can remove it with

```
button
{
    border: none;
}
```

Demo with your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/c76mkcaq/

Comment: Please don't remove the border.  That is an important usability cue.  If you are navigating items using the keyboard, the border displays what currently has focus.  Don;t make the assumption that everyone will be using a mouse with your site.

Comment: @JeffClarke The CSS has no relevance to your use case. The border highlight indication is independent of the element border.

Comment: @JeffClarke You should say that at [**No one knows**' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29992563/2302862) ;)

Answer (score 0):

The border is likely coming from the default style of the browser. If you're not using a reset like [`normalize.css`](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) (which you should), you can use the following to reset it:

```
button {
  border: 0 none;
  outline: 0 none;
}
```

If that doesn't solve it, you can use something like Chrome Developer Tools to find out where the style is coming from. Just right click the button and choose *inspect element*. You can then see all CSS selectors applied to the right in the developer tools pane.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble isn't that you didn't code this boder in, it's that you didn't code it OUT. Browsers have a default set of styles and that's what you're seeing. The default here looks like it's `border: 3px outset #ccc` but you don't want that.

Just add `border: none;` so your final code looks like this:

```css
button {
  background: #3e779d;
  padding: 12.5px 25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 40px;
  -moz-border-radius: 40px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
}
button:hover {
  background: #28597a;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take no chances, and destroy every chance of a border; Updated for clarity, your welcome guys. *(taking all situations into consideration)*

```
button { 
  border: none; // traditional fix
  border: 0px !important; // if you got something weird goin on
  outline: 0px; // if you got something really weird goin on
}
```

**and:**

```
button:hover, button:active, button:focus {
  /* styling for any way a link is about to be used */
      border: none; // traditional fix
      border: 0px !important; // if you got something weird goin on
      outline: 0px; // if you got something really weird goin on
}
```

Comment: That's a bit overkill don't you think?

Comment: Please don't remove the outline on focus.  It's an important usability cue.  If you are using the keyboard to navigate the form, it let's the user know what is focused.

Comment: Most clients bring that up.. and don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

When you can delete border gradient from button you can set border style to solid.

```
   border-style: solid;
```